# SharePoint Online webpart

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpart created for SPO and is working on Chrome, Edge but on IE no. I tried all the steps from google, but without success. I also added import '@pnp/polyfill-ie11' and the error is the same:

Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
Technical Details

[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
Failed to load component "8245f35c-fcf2-4646-94ad-6acf43879d15" (ContosoWebPart). Original error: Failed to load entry point from component "8245f35c-fcf2-4646-94ad-6acf43879d15" (ContosoWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/8245f35c-fcf2-4646-94ad-6acf43879d15_0.0.2
Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'

INNERERROR:
Failed to load entry point from component "8245f35c-fcf2-4646-94ad-6acf43879d15" (ContosoWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/8245f35c-fcf2-4646-94ad-6acf43879d15_0.0.2
Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'
CALLSTACK:
Error

Could you please help ?

thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the polyfill is added BEFORE anything else? You need to make sure of that otherwise the polyfill does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of the library are you using? As far as I know, IE11 is no longer supported since v2. If you need to enable IE mode, then you need to configure accordingly. Just refer to this doc: [IE11 Mode](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/ie11-mode/).